# Internationalization of QGIS processing scripts

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, internationalization

How can one translate QGIS processing scripts GUI and user messages to other languages ?

The QGIS documentation [explains](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/plugins.html#files-and-directory) how to translate Python plugins, but not processing scripts.

Comment: I don't understand how that could possibly work.  You can't change the script language - it's a programming language, not a natural language.  You can't translate it, unless you rewrite it in a different programming language.

Comment: We're talking about internationalization support here : processing script description, full name, text displayed to the user, ...

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways to achieve this, but if it's only for a handful of additional languages you can do something like this:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings

settings = QSettings()

description = 'description in English'
if settings.value('locale/userLocale')[0:2] == 'de':
  description = 'description in German'

print(description)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a good workaround for the description text, but it's too heavy to set up for log messages and parameters names.